# How to make a controller fire a function in a directive (Controller take to directive)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

in angular js i am trying to remove button when HTTP response returns success the HTTP call is made in a controller and the their is directive that removes ui. So how can i make the controller fires a function in the directive.

```
angular.module("AccApp").directive('transaction',['Session', function(Session){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        replace:'true',
        scope:{
            transaction:'=',
            delete:'&',
            confirm:'&',
            edit:'&'
        },
        templateUrl:"Partials/transaction.html" ,
        controller:'TransactionFileController',



        link: function(scope,element,attributes,controller){
           //variable to trace the state of content
            scope.contentDisplayed=false;
            var x ="mmmm";            
            if(Session.get_user_role() != true || scope.transaction.Confirmed == true){
                element.find('#confirm').remove();
            }

            if(Session.get_user_id() != scope.transaction.UserID && Session.get_user_role() != true){
                element.find('#delete').remove();
                element.find('#edit').remove();
            }

            element.find('.transaction-trigger').on("click",function(){
                //display and hide the transaction content
                element.find(".transaction-details").toggle(400);

                 scope.contentDisplayed=! scope.contentDisplayed;
                //request conent from server
                if( scope.contentDisplayed)
                {
                   scope.GetTransThumbs(scope.transaction.TrnID);
                }

            });


            if(scope.transaction.TrnType===true)
                {element.find('#type').html("+");}
            else if(scope.transaction.TrnType===false)
                {element.find('#type').html("-");}
        } 

    }

}]);

<div ng-repeat="trn in group.Transactions" >    
                            <transaction thumbnails="thumbnails" transaction="trn" edit="editTrns(trn)"  delete="deleteTrns(trn)" confirm="confirmTrns(trn.TrnID)"> </transaction> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll be honest, I haven't browsed all your code. Regardless, the most common way of executing a function inside a directive from the controller is achieved like so:

(Since you're already using an isolated scope, it makes things easier)

**UNTESTED CODE**

**Directive**

```
    angular.module('myapp').directive('myDirective',function(){

       return {
           restrict:'E,A',
           replace: true,
           templateUrl: 'your template.html path',
           scope:{
             myFunction:'=' // bidirectional binding here...
           },
           link : function(scope,ele,attrs){
             scope.internalCtrl = scope.myFunction || {};
             scope.internalCtrl.directiveFunction = function(){ do stuff }
           }
       }
    });
```

**Controller**

```
    angular.module('myController',function($scope){

        $scope.controllerFunction = {};
    });
```

**HTML**

```
     <button ng-click="controllerFunction.directiveFunction()">Click me to call the directive function!</button>
     <div my-directive my-function="controllerFunction"></div>
```

Comment: i am getting scope.myFunction undfiend inside the directive